# pulling more data from a table using a session(I want to display a user's data in profile format)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am struggling to display a user's profile after logging in. I can only display the user email in the session.
**below is my login script**

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , $_POST['email']);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , $_POST['password']);

     $query = "select * from users where email='$email' and         password='$password'";

     $result = $db->query($query);

     if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          if($row['status'] == 1){
              $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
              if(isset($_POST['remember_me'])){
                 setcookie("user_email" , $email , time()+60*5);
              }
              header("Location:myaccount.php");
              exit();
          }else {
              header("Location:index.php?err=" . urlencode("The user account is not activated!"));
              exit();
          }
    } else {
          header("Location:index.php?err=" . urlencode("Wrong Email or   Password!"));
          exit();
    }
}
```

After the user logins, they get redirected to this page `"myaccount.php`"

This displays only the user email only, I need to pull more user data from the table.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any data to session

like this

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'] ; 
 $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'] ; 
 $_SESSION['family'] = $row['family'] ;
```

so

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    $query = "select * from users where email='$email' and         password='$password'";

    $result = $db - > query($query);

    if ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['status'] == 1) {
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['family'] = $row['family'];
            if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
                setcookie("user_email", $email, time() + 60 * 5);
            }
            header("Location:myaccount.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            header("Location:index.php?err=".urlencode("The user account is    not activated!"));
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location:index.php?err=".urlencode("Wrong Email or   Password!"));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,It worked for only one field which is  name,as for the rest I am getting, "unidentified index error" when I try to load user data in "myacount.php"